# phpunit неправильное поведение assertEquals

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Пробую писать тесты, пока ещё в этом новичок, и наткнулся на, как мне кажется, нелогичность в поведении метода assertEquals, просьба к знающим помочь и разъяснить что да как.
Отдаю методу такие значения [true, true],[false, true],[4, true] в результате получаю что 1 и 3 тест проходит, второй нет, но как 3 тест (4 и true) по идеи должен выдавать ошибку.

Comment: Ну как бы все верно, ведь `4 == true`. Если вам нужна проверка `4 === true`, то вместо `assertEquals` вам надо использовать `assertSame`, но тогда, например, будет давать ошибку на `'123' === 123`

Comment: Понятно, не знал о существовании assertSame, так что считал что assertEquals проверяет все таки как 4 === true.
А так, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае надо было использовать assertSame вместо assertEquals.

> Ну как бы все верно, ведь 4 == true. Если вам нужна проверка 4 ===
>   true, то вместо assertEquals вам надо использовать assertSame, но
>   тогда, например, будет давать ошибку на '123' === 123 –  BOPOH 9 июн в
>   2:50

Написал ответ что бы закрыть вопрос.